# JUnit 5 with Spring boot - how repeat test with different profiles?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5

Here is classical example of the JUnit 5 data-driven test.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class ScrathTest {
  @Autowired
  private MyBean myBean;

  @ParameterizedTest
  @ValueSource(ints = {1, 3, 5, -3, 15, Integer.MAX_VALUE}) // six numbers
  void isOdd_ShouldReturnTrueForOddNumbers(int number) {
    myBean.doSomeThing(number)
  }
}
```

But what if I need to run this not for integer array, but profiles array? I mean I create a single test, and 3 test profiles then repeat this test 3 times with different profiles in each innovation. Is it possible?

**Note**

`@ActiveProfile` annotation is not a solution because it simply activates listed profiles without test repeating and context recreation.

Comment: probably you can use `ArgumentsSource` (https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-ArgumentsSource) and read different profiles and push it as an argument to the Stream

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that `JUnit5` provides a similar feature. But, you can create an abstract class and derived class will specify the active profile.

```
class abstract AbstactScrathTest {

  @Autowired
  protected MyBean myBean;

  @ParameterizedTest
  @ValueSource(ints = {1, 3, 5, -3, 15, Integer.MAX_VALUE}) // six numbers
  void isOdd_ShouldReturnTrueForOddNumbers(int number) {
    myBean.doSomeThing(number)
  }

}

@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test1")
class ScrathTestWithTestProfile1 extends AbstractScrathTest{
}


@Slf4j
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test2")
class ScrathTestWithTestProfile2 extends AbstractScrathTest{
}
```